# How do I get the value from an adjacent cell using Google Script in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I apologise if this has been asked before but I've looked for an example and unfortunately I'm unable to find an answer hence why I'm asking here.

If I have a custom function in a Google Spreadsheet how do I get the value of a cell if the contents are dynamically generated. I can get the value when it's a fixed value but not when it's dynamic.

Comment: Posting the code of the custom function and the function as you enter it into the spreadsheet with required arguments would better enable lucid help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an example of getting the adjacent cell's value whether it's dynamic (created with a function or it's a flat value)

```
function getAdjacentValue() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  return range2.getValue();
}
```

Comment: this no longer works: Cannot find method getRange(number,number)