# How to go to a cell relative to another using google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

This question is covered for [google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691654/766570), however I would like to know how to do it using google API (specifically python).

Given a certain column/cell in a google sheet, is there a way to go to cell say, 5 columns to the right, or the 3 rows down? I couldn't find anything like that in the Google Sheets api v4

Answer (score 0):

Sheets API doesn't have such functionality. Try to file a request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request). Sheets API uses the [A1 Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation). You can see the read cell methods in [Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I initially tried to do it via Google API directly, and just like you, I wasn't able to find relevant documentation.  I eventually decided to use this wrapper https://github.com/burnash/gspread which allows for this functionality easily:

```
 cell1 = mySheet.sheet.acell('c6')
 cell2 = mySheet.sheet.cell(cell1.row + 5, cell1.col+3)
```